# Why does bash add single quotes to unquoted failed pathname expansions in a command before executing it?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, trace

I was exploring the tracing of commands using [`set -x`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) (`set +x` to unset) in [`bash`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/print_cmd.c?id=ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961#n516):

> Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select
>   commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or
>   associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are
>   executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant
>   value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

Now consider the following, tracing the use of the the bash builtin [`echo \[-neE\] \[arg …\]`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) command with and *without* quotes:

```
# set -x        # what I typed
# echo 'love'   # ...
+ echo love     <--(1) the trace
love            # the output

# echo love?    # note the input contains no quote whatsoever
+ echo 'love?'  <--(2) note the trace contains quotes after returning word
love?           # i.e. failed to find any file 

# echo 'love?'  # note the input contains single quotes
+ echo 'love?'  <--(3) traces like (2)
love?

# touch loveu   # we create a file that matches the love? pattern
+ touch loveu

# echo love?    # of course now, the pattern matches the created file now
+ echo loveu    <--(4) indeed it finds it and expands to name
loveu           # the name is echoed
```

So `?` is indeed interpreted in this case as a [special character](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) used for *pattern matching* one single character in *pathname expansion*. Sure enough, once a file matching the pattern was created in the current directory, the match occurred and the name of the file was printed. Of course this behavior is [documented](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion):

> If no matching file names are found, and the shell option nullglob is
>   disabled, the word is left unchanged.

But the thing is that the word in (2) is unquoted `love?` not `'love?'`. The trace shows the state before [command execution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) but *after* expansion, and as we're seeing there is pathname expansion because of `?` and there were no matches in the first case(2) we used the special character. So the single quotes appear in that case, just as when we use single quotes(3) ourselves with the same string? Whereas in the other cases there was either a literal or the match was found and accordingly "replaced" the pattern in the command. This seems to be what is meant in the manual section on [quote removal](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal) right after expansion:

> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the
>   characters ‘\’, ‘'’, and ‘"’ that *did not result* from one of the
>   above expansions are removed. (my italics)

So here(2) we have unquoted occurrences of `'` which result from the prior expansion. I did not put them there; bash did, and now they're *not removed* - and we're just before the execution of the command.

---

*Similar illustration with `for`*

Consider this list used in a `for name [ [in [words …] ] ; ] do commands; done` loop<sup>1</sup> , with no matching file:

```
# for i in love love? 'love?'; do echo $i; done
+ for i in love 'love?' ''\''love?'\'''
+ echo love
love
+ for i in love 'love?' ''\''love?'\'''
+ echo 'love?'
love?
+ for i in love 'love?' ''\''love?'\'''
+ echo 'love?'
love?
```

So the `echo` command behavior is quite the same but in the case of the items in the `for` construct, it seems like it's trying to... escape itself quoting my quotes?? I'm uncertain...

---

**Questions**

- Why is an unquoted failed pathname expansion pattern denoted with `single quotes` in the context(2); expansion is completed anyway and we're going to execute? Again, we've completed expansion already and the pattern failed - nothing should have to expand anymore. I guess what I'm asking is why do we care at this point - the point we're at is just before 3.7.2-4 in the bash manual. Why isn't this left "as is" and expansion is simply turned off for command execution i.e. something like `set -f`?
- (What is the `for` loop doing with my single quoted item in the list?)

---

<sup>1. When using such a word list construct with for, it's really a list of items and the values are for convenience really as I find</sup> `t="0"; for i in 0 0 0 0; do let t++; echo "yes, this is really $t times"; done` <sup>quite convincing.</sup>

Comment: I'm happy to have found this question.   I've found some examples where the execution within a script fails, but if you copy paste the delimited output of -x the result then succeeds.  It's a bit frustrating.  I guess the best thing is to start a new question.

Comment: is there anyway to turn this off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When instructed to echo commands as they are executed ("execution trace"), both `bash` and `ksh` add single quotes around any word with one of several types of meta-characters<sup>1</sup>.

The meta-characters could have gotten into the word in a variety of ways. The word (or part of it) could have been quoted with single or double quotes, the characters could have been escaped with a `\`, or they remained as the result of a failed filename matching attempt. In all cases, the execution trace will contain single-quoted words, for example:

```
$ set -x
$ echo foo\;bar
+ echo 'foo;bar'
```

**This is just an artifact of the way the shells implement the execution trace; it doesn't alter the way the arguments are ultimately passed to the command.** The quotes are added, printed, and discarded. Here is the relevant part of the `bash` source code, `print_cmd.c`:

```
/* A function to print the words of a simple command when set -x is on. */
void
xtrace_print_word_list (list, xtflags)
...
{
  ...
  for (w = list; w; w = w->next)
    {
      t = w->word->word;
      ...
      else if (sh_contains_shell_metas (t))
        {
          x = sh_single_quote (t);
          fprintf (xtrace_fp, "%s%s", x, w->next ? " " : "");
          free (x);
        }
```

As to why the authors chose to do this, the code there doesn't say. But here's some similar code in `variables.c`, and it comes with a comment:

```
/* Print the value cell of VAR, a shell variable.  Do not print
   the name, nor leading/trailing newline.  If QUOTE is non-zero,
   and the value contains shell metacharacters, quote the value
   in such a way that it can be read back in. */
void
print_var_value (var, quote)
...
{
  ...
  else if (quote && sh_contains_shell_metas (value_cell (var)))
    {
      t = sh_single_quote (value_cell (var));
      printf ("%s", t);
      free (t);
    }
```

So possibly it's done so that it's easier to copy the command lines from the output of the execution trace and run them again.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>The characters that would be quoted are: IFS whitespace (space, tab, newline), quoting chars (single and double quotes, backslash), shell meta-characters (`|`, `&`, `;`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`), reserved words (`!`, `{`, `}`), globbing characters (`*`, `[`, `?`, `]`, `^`), expansion characters (`$`, backtick), possibly tilde, possibly `#`. See towards the end of [`lib/sh/shquote.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/sh/shquote.c#n390).</sub>

Comment: Thank you! You read in my desire to figure out in this particular case if the quotes were the result of shell syntax (and nowhere in the bash manual is it said that a word is returned quoted when expansion fails in this context) or of the C program that implements it. A subset of the latter as it turns out. Seems like C will be required reading...

Answer (score 1):

Because inside apostrophes ("single quotes") it is *defined* not to do any expansions, while inside quotes expansions are performed... check your manual carefully.

The shell globbing expands certain characters, i.e. `*` and `?`. If no filename matches, it returns just the original. I.e., if you have only files `lovers`, `love1`, and `love2`, then `love?` expands to `love1 love2`, `love*` expands to `love1 love2 lovers`, while `hate?` gives just `hate?`. Experiment a bit...

Comment: The shell globbing expands certain characters, i.e. `*` and `?`. If no filename matches, it returns just the original. I.e., if you have only files `lovers`, `love1`, and `love2`, then `love?` expands to `love1 love2`, `love*` expands to `love1 love2 lovers`, while `hate?` gives just `hate?`. Experiment a bit...

Comment: @vonbrand I think that last comment you made is exactly what the question is asking and should be added to your answer.