# `echo "${var}"` outputs leading spaces

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, echo

could someone help me? I am trying to create a lot of files, but when I try to write to it with echo it adds a space and single quotes, for example:

```
' (here is the space)  file.tmp' 

'  file1.tmp'

'  file3.tmp'
```

the code is this.

```
cat limpio.tmp | while read line; do
  srcip=$(echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $1}')
  destip=$(echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $2}')
  port=$(echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $NF}')
  echo "${srcip}" >> "$destip.tmp"
done
```

The problem comes when I try to iterate and view its content with cat and I can't because of the spaces.

thank you very much

Comment: Could you show a representative sample of the `limpio.tmp` file? Also, why don't you just do `awk -F, '{ print $1 >>($2 ".tmp") }' limpio.tmp`?

Comment: bro it because i want to fill this files later sorry for the new question but i dont undestand you code bro

Comment: this is the limpio.tmp                                                                                                                      174.18.418.83, 10.404.401.94, 53144 and all lines are like this.

Comment: Adding information to the comments is no use. Please add it to your question and format it. Make it easy for people who want to help you

Comment: So the spaces are part of your data it seems. Consider updating your question with the data. Make sure to use the markup tools provided to format the data as code to make it more obvious what the input file looks like.  If the spaces are part of you data, you may want to change your question it "how do I remove the spaces?".

Comment: Posting an **exact** example of the input file (showing multiple lines) and an **exact** example of your required output would make it a *lot* easier to understand your question. Also, [edit] and post them in your question (correctly formatted) and *not* in the comments.

Comment: note that you're not showing how you looked at the filenames, but current versions of GNU ls wrap filenames in single quotes by default if they contain e.g. whitespace. Your script doesn't look like it would add any quotes, so what you're seeing there is likely just due to `ls`.

Comment: Truco, please remember to accept the answer that worked best for you. Use the tick mark ✔ next to the voting buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `echo` utility inserts spaces, but only as delimiters between arguments when outputting them:

```bsh
$ echo 1    2 3       4 'A B     C'
1 2 3 4 A B     C
```

The spaces between `B` and `C` are preserved as these are part of the same argument to `echo`.

So it isn't that `echo` is *inserting* spaces, but rather that your data already contains spaces.

I'm assuming that the single quotes that you see are part of the output from `ls` on your system (see [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679)), or possibly part of the shell's tracing output while it's running with `set -x` active (see [Why does bash add single quotes to unquoted failed pathname expansions in a command before executing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118403)).  That is, it's not actually part of the filenames but only some tool's way of rendering the names.

Assume, for example, that your input looks like

```
174.18.418.83, 10.404.401.94, 53144
174.18.418.83, 10.404.401.94, 53144
174.18.418.83, 10.404.401.94, 53144
```

You will notice that there are spaces after the comma delimiters.  If you read the 2nd field from the above file using the comma as the delimiter, you will therefore retain the space(s) at the start of the field, and if you use that data as a filename, the filename will start with space.

(The observant reader will notice that the code in the question uses the variable `line` unquoted, this means that the shell would split the variable's value on the spaces and present `echo` with separate arguments like `174.18.418.83,`, `10.404.401.94,`, and `53144`.  So *it is true*, in a sense, that it is `echo` that inserts the spaces that needs to be removed, but it would not do that had there been no spaces/tabs in the data to start with. See also [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694))

The solution is to use both the comma and any subsequent blank character as the delimiter with `awk`:

```bsh
awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '{ print $2 }'
```

The expression `,[[:blank:]]*` matches comma followed by any number of blank characters.  A "blank" character is a space or a tab.  You may change this to `, *` ("comma, space, asterisk") if you know you have literal spaces.

Now to avoid calling `awk` *three* times for each line in the input file.

The `print` statement in `awk` can be "redirected" in pretty much the same way as you may redirect output in the shell, using `>` followed by a filename.

The filename you seem to want to use is whatever is in the 2nd field, with `.tmp` appended.

This mean you can replace the whole loop in your question with the following single `awk` command:

```bsh
awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '{ print $1 > ($2 ".tmp") }' limpio.tmp
```

The expression `($2 ".tmp")` evaluates to the string resulting from adding `.tmp` to whatever is in the 2nd field.

Using `>` with `print` means that the output file will be created or truncated (emptied) on the first `print` and that only subsequent `print` to the same name would append new lines. If you were to use `>>` in place of `>`, the first `print` would append to the file rather than truncate the file.

There is no built-in check for sanity here, so the above may clobber important files anywhere on the system where you have write access, depending on what's in the 2nd column of the input.

If you use GNU `awk`, then this is all you need to do. But if you use some other `awk` and need to write to a vast number of files, you may need to manually call `close()` on the files as you have processed them, or you may run out of available file descriptors.

```bsh
awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '{ fn = $2 ".tmp"; print $1 >>fn; close(fn) }' limpio.tmp
```

Here, I'm saving the output filename in a variable, `fn`.  I then append the output to that file, and then I close the file.  This ensures that I won't exhaust the available file descriptors, but it also requires me to always use `>>` with `print` and manually clean up (remove) the output files if I need to run the `awk` command again.

GNU `awk` keeps track of how many file descriptors have been opened and starts closing them if needed (and re-opens the files for appending if further data needs to be written to a file later).

See also:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Comment: Thanks for the support bros i solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you originally posted:

```
cat limpio.tmp | while read line; do
  srcip=$(echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $1}')
  destip=$(echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $2}')
  port=$(echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $NF}')
  echo "${srcip}" >> "$destip.tmp"
done
```

That is unnecessarily complicated. Seeing that you're reading comma delimited fields, you could read them directly into variables:

```
while IFS=$' \t\n,' read -r srcip destip port junk ;do
  echo "$srcip" >> "${destip}.tmp"
done <limpio.tmp
```

Comment: This seems to solve the user's issue, given that the input file contains spaces. However, your answer does not try to diagnose the issue, nor does it explain how it is solved by your code.  If you just want to add a comma to the default value of `IFS`, btw, you could use `IFS=$IFS, read ...`.  You may also want to use `printf` rather than `echo` as `echo` has a tendency to change data under certain circumstances.

Comment: @they : The OP seems happy with his echo, and the echo is not really the problem. We are not going to teach him EVERYTHING in just one posting. Adding more complications will  only distract him from understanding what we're doing here.

Comment: Sure, forget about the `printf` then.  Just describe how your solution solves the issue, and what the issue actually was.  Because now it's just "here's another way to do what you're doing (and it solves the problem but I'm not telling you why)".

Comment: Also note that there is a security issue in that the user is writing to files named by input data, and that this may overwrite existing files if the data contains paths of existing files (anywhere on the system where the user may write).

Comment: I swapped `echo` for `printf` because a value starting with `-` or containing `\ ` may break `echo`. The `echo` command is non-standard and works in different ways in different places. `printf` is consistent

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix probably is to remove the double-quotes in `echo "${srcip}"`.

See yourself:

```sh
var=' spacy '
echo X$(echo "$var")X
echo X$(echo $var)X
```